# Vue js is not render in Laravel 5.8

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have developed a vue js with laravel application.in localhost it's just working fine , but after migrating to the live server the app.js not rendered in the root element.is there any one know what's the problem is?

Comment: Did you check the browser console? Make sure all script URLs actually point to files?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: have you installed node and dependencies on the server?

Comment: I already installed node_modules.and i run the npm run watch to mix them.our server does not suppprt node.so i locally installed and pull through the git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must upload the app.js file found in public / js / app.js to the new server

If you use git, you should always upload this file when you create or modify components, since it is the last performance that the browser will interpret.

Comment: I already upload the final app.js mix file in to the public.but it doesn't work